# PHP regex multi-line

Tags: php, regex, multiline

I have the following PHP regex

```
preg_match('/[\/\/\*] First: (.*)\n[\/\/\*] Second: (.*)\n/i', $some_string)
```

but for some reason it will not match this text:

```
// First: a string
// Second: another string
```

I tried changing line endings between Windows and Unix style, this did nothing. I also tried splitting up the regex to match First and Second separately; this worked but when I put them both together they no longer match the sample text. It seems to have something to do with the space after the second `[\/\/\*]`.. any ideas?

Note I can't change the regex; this is client code that I reversed because they don't provide documentation. This code looks for certain pattern in PHP files in order to load them as 'plugins' in their product. Really I'm trying to guess what header I need to add to these PHP files so they will correctly be recognized as plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
preg_match('~// First: (.*)\n// Second: (.*)~i', $str);
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/Esd1b)

**Why is your regex wrong?**

`[\/\/\*]` is a character class that either matches a `/` or a `*`.

But you seem to have `//` at the beginning of the string, so you'll **never** get a match.

**What string will my current regex match?**

Change your current input to have a `/` at the beginning and a newline after the second line:

```
$some_string =
'/ First: a string
/ Second: another string
';
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/oc4F7)

Comment: I can't change the regex itself, that's client code I can't modify. I have to actually come up with a header for a php plugin the client code will load based on this regex rule.... :(

Comment: @Trust: your regex **is just incorrect**. You cannot do anything without changing it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$some_string = <<<STR
// First: a string
// Second: another string

STR;

$match = preg_match('`// First: (.*)\n// Second: (.*)\n`i', $some_string);

echo $match;
```

Just tested this, it works. Are you sure there's a linebreak after the second line?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Answer:

I was trying to guess what pattern this would match. It ended up being this:

```
/*
* First: a string
* Second: another string
*/
```